# Conversion from XSL-FO to PDF with Apache FOP starting from a XML file

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm new to XSL-FO programming and I need help.
I basically need to render a XSL-FO file into PDF with data from XML.

But when I try, everything appears right int the PDF (background, manually entered text) but not data that should be read from XML.

Notice that I tried only with the element "idShip".

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE shipment SYSTEM "C:\Users\informatica\Documents\workspace\PrintTest\shipment.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="shipment_to_pdf.xsl" ?>

<shipment>
    <idShip>111</idShip>
    <fare></fare>
    <to>
        <name></name>
        <surname></surname>
        <address1></address1>
        <address2></address2>
        <zip></zip>
        <city></city>
        <country></country>
        <email></email>
        <phone></phone>
    </to>
    <from>
        <name></name>
        <surname></surname>
    </from>
</shipment>
```

XSL:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master page-height="135mm"
                    page-width="216mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-left="20mm"
                    margin-right="20mm" margin-bottom="10mm" master-name="PageMaster">
                    <fo:region-body background-color="#EFAFAF"
                        margin-top="20mm" margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm"
                        margin-bottom="20mm" />

                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1"
                master-reference="PageMaster">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block text-indent="1em" font-family="sans-serif"
                        font-size="20pt" font-weight="bold" background-color="#EEEEEE"
                        line-height="20mm">

                        //this should be the problem 
                        <xsl:for-each select="shipment">
                            <xsl:value-of select="idShip" />
                        </xsl:for-each>

                     </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>


            </fo:page-sequence>     
</fo:root>
```

PDF right now renders as a block with a red background, but no data from XML.

Comment: What about `/shipment` and `idShip`?

Comment: Already tried that :( it seems like I can't write a xsl file containing both xsl-fo and xslt commands... But as I said, I'm new to this, so maybe i'm missing something

Comment: You are mixing up XSL and XSL-FO. They are two close but different things. XSL-FO (`.fo`) file should be a product of the conversion: `XML > XSL > XSL-FO > PDF`. Try to start with slowly building of the `test.fo` file. Usually, you need to fetch every part of the XML needed in the result with an XSL templates... Too broad for explanation here. You can mix them as you do but in a bit different way. See the chart [here](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xsl-fo/formatting-objects-basics.cfm) and try to follow [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: @HonzaHejzl not exactly, it is legit for a stylesheet to consist of just a literal result element together with its contents, provided it has an `xsl:version` attribute. Of course this kind of stylesheet has limitations, but for a simple input it could be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a so-called **simplified XSLT module** ([XSLT 1.1 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#result-element-stylesheet),  [XSLT 2.0 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#simplified-stylesheet)) which is *almost* correct, it is only missing the `xsl:version` attribute in the root element.

Just add `xsl:version="1.0"` (or `2.0` if you need the new features *and* your XSLT processor supports them) to the `fo:root` element and you should get the expected result.

Note that a simplified stylesheet has some limitations, as you cannot define parameters, global variables, functions (if using XSLT 2.0), keys and other templates.